# iOS 8 Beta - Internal Testers have to be technicals?

Tags: testing, ios8, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

I tried moving to the Apple Beta-Testing system from TestFlight. So far it did look promising, 25 internal testers that could receive builds without having to put the app through a review process and an "amazing" number of one thousand external Beta-Testers.

While I did not yet look into the external Beta-Program, I'm having some difficulties with the internal Beta-Program.

All internal testers have to be either Admins, Legals or Technicals - while some of the internal Testers might indeed are Developers that have to have at least technicals, others are not.

Now I have to give all of my internal testers at least "Technical"-Access meaning they could also modify my apps. Also, they receive emails every time the server-side check of iTunesConnect finds something it doesn't consider okay.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: I have same trouble... it's so stupid like all in Apple.. And Close Testflightapp.com stupids idiots ... i hate Apple for this manipulations.... Now our Internal Tester can delete create modify all aps in my team....!!

Comment: i start a trade in apple forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1097073#1097073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use External-Testers instead Internal.
For it:

> You need to fill out the required information if you want to try using
>   external testing.

Give a few answers, and send to Review. 
This review must be faster then Release review.

I hope this information helped you.

And nobody cancel use thirty party apps as http://hockeykit.net for example.

Comment: That's how i deal with it now too. Since the review is super-fast it's not much of a big deal to use external testers instead.